# How to make a storm release from the source code?

Tags: java, maven, release, apache-storm

I need to create the latest "release" from the source code on github. But having trouble doing it.

here is the source code : https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm
here is how release looks like: https://storm.incubator.apache.org/downloads.html

My maven and java knowledge are very limited.
 I've tried this:
`mvn release:prepare` but it fails with this error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project storm: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]`

`pom.xml` wasn't changed https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/pom.xml

If someone can otline me the steps on how to build a release it would be awesome.
Thank you.

##UPDATED

`mvn release:prepare -X`

```
[INFO] [DEBUG] Generating signature for /home/bsmith/workspace/storm/incubator-storm/target/storm-0.9.2-incubating.pom
[INFO] gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
[INFO] gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] Storm ............................................. FAILURE [4.032s]
[INFO] [INFO] maven-shade-clojure-transformer ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] Storm Core ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 4.907s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 21 09:40:45 EDT 2014
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/291M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.4:sign (default) on project storm: Exit code: 2 -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.4:sign (default) on project storm: Exit code: 2
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[INFO] Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exit code: 2
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.GpgSigner.generateSignatureForArtifact(GpgSigner.java:254)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.GpgSignAttachedMojo.execute(GpgSignAttachedMojo.java:182)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
[INFO]  ... 19 more
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Storm ............................................. FAILURE [7.220s]
[INFO] maven-shade-clojure-transformer ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Storm Core ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.198s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 21 09:40:45 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/151M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project storm: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project storm: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:232)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPrepareGoalsPhase.execute(RunPrepareGoalsPhase.java:44)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:277)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:394)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.AbstractMavenExecutor.executeGoals(AbstractMavenExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:81)
    ... 28 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

##UPDATED #2

I've tried to go with first suggestion:

```
Fork the project (on Github), change the SCM section in the POM to use your own GitHub Fork (or change the SCM entry to some local repository)
```

After I've forked a git repo I've updated a section in `pom.xml`:

```
 <scm>
     <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/XXX/incubator-storm.git</connection>
     <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/XXX/incubator-storm.git</developerConnection>
     <tag>v0.9.2-incubating</tag>
     <url>https://github.com/XXX/incubator-storm.git</url>
 </scm>
```

where `XXX` is my username.

pushed new `pom.xml` to github
run `mvn release:prepare -DpushChanges=false -Dgpg.skip=true -X`
and got an error:

```
[INFO] [DEBUG] Generating signature for /home/bsmith/workspace/storm/incubator-storm/target/storm-0.9.0.2.pom
[INFO] gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
[INFO] gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
...
...
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.4:sign (default) on project storm: Exit code: 2 -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.4:sign (default) on project storm: Exit code: 2
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
```

Comment: I can't really help you but I can tell you I once wasted many hours building another apache project because I downloaded the latest "release" in the wrong minute. The commit had some outdated paths in maven which got fixed quickly after that. So.. you could try to build an older stable release first, if the same error happens at least you know it's not some bug in their latest configuration.

Comment: good point will try it out.

Comment: Is this the whole log message? My first guess would be that git is not available on the class path. (GitHub is currently down, so I can not check).

Comment: @blackbuild I've cloned the repo and tried to create a release from my computer. And yes, I can click on this link and it will send me to the repo on github

Comment: @blackbuild I've run mvn with `-X` option end pasted the most relevant logs.

Comment: Ah, thats the problem. Default (release) build tries to sign your artifacts. Which it cannot do, since you have no default key installed. You could try `-Dgpg.skip=true`. However, see my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are just trying to make a *distribution* (like what you would download from Apache), you can do so without the maven release plugin.

First, from the root of the source code directory do a maven build (skipping tests will make it faster):

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

Then create the binary distribution:

```
cd storm-dist/binary
mvn package
```

The `.zip` and `.tar.gz` binary archives will be created in the `storm-dist/binary/target` sub-directory.

Comment: AWEAOME! Thanks! Your book is great BTW. https://www.packtpub.com/storm-distributed-real-time-computation-blueprints/book

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to do a release using maven-release-plugin.

In order for this to succeed, the release plugin would have to change the source code on GitHub, which you aren't allowed to do.

So you have several options:

- Fork the project (on Github), change the SCM section in the POM to use your own GitHub Fork (or change the SCM entry to some local repository)
- You could call maven:release with `-DpushChanges=false`, which would prevent pushing of your changes back to GitHub
- Don't use release plugin. Change the version using [maven-versions-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/), run `mvn clean install` (or deploy, after changing the distribution management section), and change the version again to a new SNAPSHOT version afterwards.

In any case, make sure that the cloned version (without release) builds cleanly on your computer.

## Update

Try the third alternativ from above:

```
mvn version:set -DnewVersion=0.9.2-incubating-homebrew
git tag 0.9.2-incubating-homebrew (if you want)
mvn clean install/deploy
mvn version:set -DnewVersion=0.9.3-incubating-hombrew-SNAPSHOT
git push
```

If the gpg problem still occurs, it would be easiest to remove the complete sign profile.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, will try it out

Comment: I've tried your suggestions, but because I have no experience with maven and apache, I stuck on one thing. I've updated my answer, because it's to big for the comment.

Comment: These suggestion where alternatives, not to be used together. I will update my answer with the easiest solution